# What is the word for 'Turning real events into fiction'?

Tags: single-word-requests

A single word or phrase for turning events (historical/recent) into fiction.Like based on real events, but fictious. Like some myths that have been derived from real events.

> 'romanticized' but that means turning things into good/idealistic.I'm looking for a word that is neutral.

Comment: Are you looking for a verb or a term for the genre? Please include an example sentence.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Some information will help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to include the desired register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and if possible *provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage*.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”, “[single-word-requests tag wiki](/tags/single-word-requests/info)”.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Fictionalise](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fictionalize) (Am. Eng fictionalize)

> verb
>
> To fictionalize an account of something that really happened
> means to tell it as a story, with some details changed or added.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Alternatives that do not literally mean this, but should almost always be read as such are: "Based on actual events" and "Based on a true story".

Comment: In wikitionary they attributed  'alter real events by adding flasehood' to it's meaning , but thanks for the definition :).

Answer (score 14):

"Fictionalise"/"fictionalize" (depending on local spelling) is - as already suggested - probably the closest, but I've also seen "dramatise"/"dramatize" (often as "dramatisation") used.

I want to say that the word for turning real events into fiction is "journalism", but that's probably not as helpful as I think it is.

Comment: On the 'drama' side of things, there's also the related 'dramatic license', although that doesn't fit in this context.

Comment: I like *dramatize*   But I have to -1 for *journalism*

Comment: I have to +1 for _journalism_

Answer (score 7):

A related literary term is [***roman à clef***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/roman+a+clef) ('story with a key') in which real persons and events are overlaid with fictional persons and events.

Comment: Would it still have the same meaning if the characters/events were based on real persons? Or does the characters intrinsically have to be real?

Comment: @Rum - as you can see from the linked definition, the term is a bit flexible and can be used to cover either situation. Usually, it means a thinly disguised account of a real situation and real person(s).

Answer (score 4):

[allegorise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegorize) (Am. Eng. allegorize)

Verb, from:

Noun: [allegory](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/allegory)

> figurative treatment of one subject under the guise of another.

Answer (score -1):

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:

***FACTION***
mass noun

A literary and cinematic genre in which real events are used as a basis for a fictional narrative or dramatization.

‘the current vogue for faction seems about to overwhelm narrative history.

'FACTION' is a blend of 'fact' and 'fiction'.

Comment: That’s not a verb meaning ‘turn into fiction’, though.

Comment: I'm not about to vote down, but I would disagree. Perhaps O.L.D. has incorporated a portmanteau neologism, but "faction" already has a meaning - a group, bloc, party or sect often - but not necessarily - political [thesaurus.com].

Comment: Then we can say there are two homonyms which are the result of convergence of two different words.

Comment: @user307254 - Eventually, maybe, but I don't think we're there yet. As far as I'm concerned the O.L.D. definition is just plain wrong - but I recognise I might just be part of a group, bloc, sect etc. with that view...